# momentjs returning a different result in browser than in karma unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, momentjs, karma-jasmine

I am writing some unit tests for my AngularJS app with karma and jasmine. I am also using momentjs.

When I call the same function from the moment library in the browser I get a different result than from the karma unit test.

It's breaking my unit tests.

In the browser this is what I get:

[image]

In my unit test I get a different result. For example when I call the function to get the start of the month and week I get '1' instead of 53 for the week number.

```
Calendar.data.currentCalendarMonth = moment('01-01-2017', dateFormat).clone().startOf('month');

//showing different results than in the browser
console.log(Calendar.data.currentCalendarMonth.format());
console.log(' week ', Calendar.data.currentCalendarMonth.week());
```

[image]

Here is my codepen with the reproduced bug:
https://codepen.io/aubz/pen/VNQjgV

Edit: I am using these moment dependencies in my project:

```
"moment-timezone": "0.5.4",
'moment/min/moment-with-locales.js',
'moment-timezone/builds/moment-timezone-with-data.js',
```

Comment: can you provide a gist? can't reproduce

Comment: @DanBachar done

Comment: When you insert `moment.locale()` into your browser console, what does it show? "en" or "fr" or others?

Comment: What puzzling me here is 2016 only has 52 weeks: https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2016, so your browser's result is wrong... Either because of some error in moment.js, or it's caused by `week` being affected by locale: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/week/

Comment: en in the browser and in the unit test

Comment: @blaz do you think I'd be better off using Date object?

Comment: Do you mean initialize moment by a Date object instead of String? I doubt it will work... Have you tried using `isoWeek()` instead of `week()`? https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-week/.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my app was using en-us and the unit tests were using en-gb. I had to explicitly set the locale in moment in the unit tests.

```
beforeEach(inject(function (_Calendar_) {
    Calendar = _Calendar_;
    Calendar.clear();
    moment.locale('en-gb');
}));
```